# How to scroll to bottom in the Ext JS 3.4 grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a grid panel (with Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor panel inside) and I want to scroll to the bottom (near the bottom my Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor is not shown completely),

this piece of code is not working:

```
this.MyGrid.getView().on('scrollToBottom', function(){
        var inputEl = this.MyGrid.el.dom;
        inputEl.scrollTop = inputEl.scrollHeight;
    }, this);
```

.....

and then when pressing save button i fire event:

```
this.MyGrid.getView().fireEvent('scrollToBottom',this);
```

any ideas why it's not scrolling? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution! no additional events and listeners, just

```
var inputEl = this.myGrid.getView().scroller.dom;
inputEl.scrollTop = inputEl.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.on()` function is used to set up a listener function for an event, not add a custom event.
Similarly, the `.fireEvent()` function is used to trigger an event on an object. AFAIK you can't define you're own events, and there is no "scrollToBottom" event in ExtJs.

What you'll want to do is define your scrollToBottom code as a function, and then call this from your save button click handler

Comment: We can define our own  event using the addEvent method and later on fire it based on our requirement .

Comment: 'this.scrollToBottom(); .... scrollToBottom: function() {
        var inputEl = this.characteristics.el.dom;
        inputEl.scrollTop = inputEl.scrollHeight;
    },' it goes inside function, but scrolling is not happening

Comment: @user3505689 is your function associated with the event is invoking?

Comment: @user3505689 I think you should add your event as a listenerto the gid and then handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add an event to your grid using *addEvent* method(using init) and then add the event as the listener to your grid.
Fire the event whenever necessary(In your case when user hits the save button.) using *fireEvent* method and subscribe it in your listener.

Example code looks like the below(You have to add this event and then fire it.) Adding the event in the *init* component looks like below(in the below this refers to grid scope)

```
this.addEvents('SCROLL_TO_BOTTOM');
```

You have to subscribe the event and set your scroll  height for your grid.Add the below listener to your grid.

```
listeners: {
         'SCROLL_TO_BOTTOM': this.handleScroll,
         scope: this
         }
```

Function for handling the scroll

```
 handleScroll:function(){   
           var inputEl = this.MyGrid.el.dom;
           inputEl.scrollTop = inputEl.scrollHeight;
         }
```

Hope this helps you...